# How to select multiple cells and copypaste to another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to select multiple cells and After selecting multiple cells,I want to copy and past the values in other sheet.

My code is this:

Union(Range("C4,C5,I4,I5,J7"), Range("C4, C5, I4, I5, J7")).Select

Selection.Copy

code selecting the cells, however whiles going to "Selection. Copy" arguments it gives Run time error '1004'
"That command cannot be used on multiple selections."

can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would do it one piece at a time:

```
Sub Disjoint()
  Dim rng As Range, r As Range, addy As String
  Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1,B3,C5,D7,E11")
  For Each r In rng
    addy = r.Address
    r.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range(addy)
  Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: it's copying and pasting now, however I want all cells should be pasted in Transpose mode I do have below code for this below:                     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks   :=False, Transpose:=True

Comment: I want all cells should copy in one go and want to paste them as value Transpose=true

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it pastes to the next available column in Sheet 2 row 1

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Set rng = Range("C4,C5,I4,I5,J7")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        c.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
    Next c
End Sub
```